# Build up url in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Im making a applikation in django and im totaly new to to language python and framework django.

My problem is i can't figure out how to get this url:

```
project/2/ticket/1
```

Im in `project/2` and got an link in my template that links to `project/2/ticket/1`.
The error i get is `NoReverseMatch at /project/1` and the code im using is:

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

# Project urls below 
 url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)$', 'project_manager.views.project_list', name='project_list_with_ticket'),
 url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/ticket/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)$', 'project_manager.views.ticket_list', name='ticket_list'),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

**views.py**

```
def ticket_list(request, ticket_id = None):

if ticket_id:

    tickets = get_list_or_404(Ticket.objects.filter(id = ticket_id))

    return render(request, 'tickets/details.html', {"tickets" : tickets })

else:

    return render(request, 'projects/list.html', {'projects' : projects })
```

**my template**

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
    <div class="tickets">
        <a href="{% url ticket_list ticket.id %}">{{ ticket }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT --**
It says there is no ticket_list, but there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `ticket_list` URL/View with one variable - `ticket.id` - when it requires two.

Your template:

`<a href="{% url ticket_list ticket.id %}">{{ ticket }}</a>`

You are passing a `ticket.id` and it also requires a `project.id` as you can see in your URL:

`url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/ticket/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)$', 'project_manager.views.ticket_list', name='ticket_list'),`

You need to change your template to pass both variables that you are asking for in the URL. You haven't posted how you get the project id, so my code will probably not work exactly as posted, but you need something like this:

`<a href="{% url ticket_list ticket.project.id ticket.id %}">{{ ticket }}</a>`

The order that the variables are passed need to align with the way that they are asked for in your URL. Since your URL asks for a `project_id` and then a `ticket_id`, make sure you pass them in your template in that order as outlined above.